# Automating key strokes for desktop application

Tags: java, ruby, automation, desktop-application

I have a desktop application, to use that I need to login to it every time. But I want to automate this login process.

I want to write a little program which will:

1. load my desktop application (in a scheduled time)
2. type the user name
3. type the password
4. click the login button

My concern is, is this possible with a Desktop application? If possible what is the path I should follow?

I'm have worked with both Java and Ruby, so if I could get something developed by those two languages that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be around a four-line script in [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), as it has function primitives that closely map to your operations.

Answer (score 4):

I would advise using AutoIt if you are on Windows, it can do everything that you need easily.
http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Also useful if you like python, there's a cool program called Sikuli that you should check out.
http://sikuli.org/

Comment: when AutoIt was not in maven repository, before 2018, was hard to find the exact libs. NOw, its okay.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without programming. There are many applications that can save a user's scenario and repeat it many times !!! (that is helpful for stress testing).

Take a look at IBM Rational Robot. You can also find many similar free tools.

Comment: Hi @hsalimi, will check IBM Rational Robot, thanks

Answer (score 0):

More details about your test environment (Windows, Mac, Linux) and what the technology the GUI is made of (Windows GUI, Qt, embedded browser), etc. would be very helpful for determining what solution is best for you.

If you are one Windows and dealing with native controls, [RAutomation](http://rubygems.org/gems/rautomation) is a great gem that should do what you need. It even has an [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) adapter mode which makes it a strict superset of AutoIt functionality.

If you need more power, consider checking out the Windows UI Automation framework. It's mostly in .NET but you maybe able to find or write a Java or Ruby wrapper around it. See a .NET example [here](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/06/introduction-to-ui-automation-with.html).

If you are dealing with a UI which is an embedded web browser, then consider using [watir-webdriver](http://rubygems.org/gems/watir-webdriver) to drive it. You need some platform specific code to get the embedded browser instance and bind to it. The rest should feel just like a web application.

Finally, the mention of [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/) is certainly a good one for being able to deal with any UI without needing an API. It's also Jython (yay JVM!). That said, I've found it to be fiddly and brittle, even more than typical UI testing due to its lack of identification of elements based upon either IDs or some kind of object hierarchy and relying solely on appearance. That said, it's really quick to be up and running so give it a shot.

Comment: Hi peakxu, Yes m on windows and this is a Desktop UI, thanks for the answer